# How to determine if arccos is even in Java?

Tags: double, trigonometry

I am trying to program a calculator and when the result is even, i.e. an integer, the display should show an integer and not in deciaml format.

For many cases it suffices to just do the following:

```
   if(variable % 1 == 0)
            ...;
```

However, for the trigonometric functions this does not work. For example when I calculate arccos(0.5) this should equal 60 degrees (if I concert it to degrees).

However when I calculate it:

```
   double result = 180.0 * Math.Pi * Math.acos(0.5);
```

I get something like

```
   result = 60.000000000001
```

and hence the test with % 1 fails. How can I do this most efficiently? Do I have to set a delta value which I compare with? But this delta value must be extremely small then since I also want to be able to calculate with small physical constantst such as ...E-34.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BigDecimal` and specify your desired precision.

Comment: But how would you do that? I mean, Math.acos(0.5) returns a double so I already lost the precision, havent I? Do I have to specify my own PI as a BigDecimal from a String to get all decimals?